# JIRA Hide fields in View

Tags: jira

I have certain issues that are secure and should not be viewed by all roles. I'm looking for a way to only show the summary on the view screen but no other details unless a certain role views it. Some sort of way to flag an issue on creation to hide certain fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other easy ways to do this.but one solution that comes to my mind is use of [Behaviours plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours).using this plugin can hide fields if certain user logged into the system.

you can follow steps like this..

1.install Behaviours plugin and create new behaviour then add mappings and go to the fiels and do the relevant configurations...

[image: sample behaviour]

2.then you can add fields you want to hide and add conditions to them. then there is a option to add certain user roles in the condition configuration page.

[image: sample condition page]

3.then click on the hide link on the Field page.

Note-the Behaviours plugin is part of the Script Runner plugin now.you can use either Behaviours plugin s or  [Script Runner plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner)

Comment: Hello! I know this question is tool old, but I am having difficulty with the step that was glossed over here. "then you can add fields you want to hide and add conditions to them".  I can't get the conditions to work. Do you happen to know which approach to take to hide fields?